# I setup Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking, but data not populating in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've reviewed multiple blogs on how to set this up, followed all instructions like enabling Ecommerce in GA, data layer in GTM, etc.

Using GA Debug and Tag Assistant to troubleshoot. The data layer transaction data is on page and recognized by tag assistant.

[image: Data Layer on Tag Assistant]

GA Debug does show an error, but not sure why:

[image: GA Debug Issue]

The tag is firing on the correct page after a transaction, and verified this with GTM preview mode.

Doesn't work and keep looking to see what the issue is, but can't figure it out, and hoping someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: it looks as your transaction data are pushed to dataLayer after gtm.js event. So if your tag is triggered by 'PaggeView' trigger type then this data will be unavailable. Consider switching to DOM ready trigger or push your transaction data with en event and use custom event trigger.
Here is the sample code working with Page View trigger http://ppchead.com/ec_test.html. Take a look on an order of dataLayer objects.

Comment: @ДмитроБулах Please submit as answer so I can mark as correct because I changed from Page View to DOM Ready on the Thank You page and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks as your transaction data are pushed to dataLayer after gtm.js event. So if your tag is triggered by 'PaggeView' trigger type then this data will be unavailable. Consider switching to DOM ready trigger or push your transaction data with en event and use custom event trigger.